# Why is v-model not working properly, returning'' Property "modelValue" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.'' Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

The Component I am making is a basic toggle switch  made in vue using tailwind. during the initial render the switch is in an incorrect position, first click toggles the theme but the switch still stays the same, third click and forward the switch works properly

Switch.vue

```
<template>
    <label class="switch relative inline-block w-[39px] h-[19px]">
        <input type="checkbox" class="w-0 h-0 opacity-0" v-model="modelValue">
        <span
            class="absolute rounded-[34px] before:rounded-[50%] cursor-pointer top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-gray-300 transition shadow-inner before:absolute before:h-[17px] before:w-[17px] before:left-[1px] before:top-[1px] before:bg-white before:transition "
            :class="[{
                'before:translate-x-5 bg-blue-500': modelValue
            }]" @click="$emit('update:modelValue', modelValue)"></span>
    </label>
</template>
```

Parent.vue

```
// darkTheme comes from a pinia store.
  <Switch v-model="darkTheme.enableDarkTheme" />
```

I was expecting the switch to work with v-model and toggle the theme, it works after a few clicks but first 3 clicks it does not toggle.

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export let useThemeStore = defineStore('darkTheme', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            enableDarkTheme: window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches,
        }
    },
    actions: {
        toggle() {
            !this.enableDarkTheme;
        }
    }
})
```

Edit: Pinia seems to be sending the prop value as undefined on the first mutation, which seems to be causing the issue. please verify the store code

Comment: Where are you defining modelValue?

Comment: Where is your props statement?

Comment: The error means there's no modelValue prop, while it's expected. Check v-model docs on how it works. It's a mistake to use nested v-model because you cannot mutate a prop

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask and Álvaro Pérez Díaz, your comments along with the docs helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to custom components v-model in the docs
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html
for v-model in custom components props and emits need to be explicitly defined in the script setup, also see @Estus's comment about nested v-model

This is a simple vue component for a toggle slider
Switch.vue

```js
<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
<template>
    <label class="switch relative inline-block w-[39px] h-[19px]">
        <input type="checkbox" class="w-0 h-0 opacity-0" :checked="modelValue">
        <span
            class="absolute rounded-[34px] before:rounded-[50%] cursor-pointer top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-gray-300 transition shadow-inner before:absolute before:h-[17px] before:w-[17px] before:left-[1px] before:top-[1px] before:bg-white before:transition "
            :class="[{
                'before:translate-x-5 bg-blue-500': modelValue
            }]" @click="$emit('update:modelValue', !modelValue)"></span>
    </label>
</template>
```

Parent Component

```js
//Inside the parent component
<Switch v-model="darkTheme.enableDarkTheme" />
```